# CrOS cannot boot from usb

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os, google-chrome-devtools

I have a Lenovo Chromebook C630, and have Developer AND Debug mode on, plus I have `crossystem dev_boot_usb=1`. I also have `enable_dev_usb_boot` on. When I get to the os verif is not on screen, I press ctrl-u. It is supposed to boot into my usb device, but instead, it just beeps at me. Can someone please help me?